# 'Chunks' missing from side of tire..Dangerous?

Tags: tires, audi, sidewall-damage

[image]

Just inherited sis in laws Audi--and discovered this chunk of tire missing from front drivers side tire. It might have been there a while. I'm torn between having to replace it  ($$/€€€) and not wanting to have an accident. Is this dangerous? Any other options? It's hard to tell from the photo but the missing chunk is maybe between 1/4 and 1/2 inch in depth. (Abt 1 to 1 1/2 CM.)... Any input greatly appreciated --Thx DP

[image]

Comment: It looks superficial, *so long as there is no other damage* like bulging tire walls that we can't see in the pictures. It's impossible to make a proper safety assessment without seeing actual tire, not just a picture.

Comment: I have the opposite view to alephzero - I would always replace a tyre with any damage, because I rely on it working correctly under heavy load. It will depend on your vehicle, driving style, risk appetite etc.

Comment: I also agree that you should definitely replace the tire. Blowouts at highway speed kill people. Your life and 4000 pounds of metal depend on these thin pieces of rubber. if that rubber didn't do anything the manufacturer wouldn't waste money putting it there...

Answer (score 1):

While this looks superficial and kind of okay, would you really risk your life, life of everyone in the car and everyone on the road just to save few bucks?

What I advise is to always go with new and reliable tires, this is the contact point between your vehicle and the road. I know someone will say buying new tires is expensive, but if you can't afford to maintain your car just sell it.

Sidewall damages are most dangerous one. The tires weakest spot is Sidewall. If you drive with this tire at high speed it can  pop out of nowhere. Since it won't be a tiny hole that will lose air gradually, but a serious pop you might lose control and crash. Just change the tire.